# The Eye of Magnus Won't Close

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I walk into the Hall of Elements and Ancano immediately starts fighting me. All of the answers say to let him talk first, but I can't if he doesn't even start talking.

When using the Staff of Magnus against the Eye of Magnus, nothing happens. Ancano isn't losing any health either.

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Skyrim is a very buggy game, but we love it anyway.

If you are playing on the PC version there are a couple of fixes you can try with the command line.

- To stop Tolfdir from running in and starting the fight prematurely, use TDetect which will stop either Ancano or Tolfdir from attacking each other, allowing the script to progress normally. TDetect can be turned back on again once the Eye of Magnus opens.

On both console and PC the following might have caused the problem, check the fixes that come with each

- You may also enter to find a member of the Psijic Order already present in the hall, skipping over the cutscene between Ancano and Tolfdir, preventing Tolfdir from finishing his cutscene. This makes the quest impossible to finish. You must reload a previous save before entering the college to continue
- If the Dragonborn encounters a Dragon before entering the college and does not kill it, the cut scene will fail to start, rendering the quest unable to be completed.
- If a magic anomaly encountered outside is left alive, upon entering the Hall of Elements, Ancano will speak the beginning lines, but Tolfdir will run into a corner preventing the Dragonborn from being able to fight Ancano. In order to fix this bug, one should go outside and kill the magic anomaly then re-enter the hall, Tolfdir should now run his proper course.

Sources: 
http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Eye_of_Magnus
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eye_of_Magnus

If all else fails you might need to reload a previous save or there is a possibility that the quest is incompletable.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and spent probably half an hour or more trying to solve it but to no avail. I got fed up with them fighting and me not being able to do anything so I went and hid by the door to the arch-mages quarters and got in my phone and in about 5 minuets the screen started to glow and they eye was activated and I was able to proceed like normal.

Comment: What does "got in my phone" mean?